# RestSharp in AWS Lambda .NetCoreApp 1.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, .net-core, restsharp

I need to use RestSharp for AWS Lambda, but when using RestSharp.NetCore 105.2.3 AWS return errors:

```
--Detected package downgrade: System.Reflection from 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04 to 4.1.0.
```

Means RestSharp is using 4.1 but AWS support 4.3 version set, for .NetCoreApp 1.0.

Do we a version with dependency on System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.4.3.0-preview1-24530-04?

Answer (score 0):

We will not be able to support .NET Core 1.X, but if you update your app to use .NET Core 2, you can use our latest package, which has a .NET Standard 2.0 library.

RestSharp.NetCore package is not from RestSharp team and is not supported by us. It is also not being updated and the owner does not respond on messages, neither the source code of the package is published.